# Insert column name as value

Tags: postgresql, database-design, schema, insert

Consider the following, in PostgreSQL:

```
drop table test ;
create table test (result1 text, red smallint, green smallint, blue smallint, results2 text) ;
insert into test values ('red',1,2,3) ;
```

I would like `results2` to contain the value `blue`, indicating that the maximum value for the integer columns occurs in column `blue`. This can be achieved by running an `UPDATE` or a function at a later time.

How do I insert the *column name* as a value? As an example, the row above would be updated such that it contains:

```
'red', 1, 2, 3, 'blue'
```

There will not be `NULL` values for the integer columns and one of the integers will always be the largest.

(See also [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101221/retrieve-column-name-as-data).)

Comment: That could still be done in a view. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: What should the column contain if two or more columns have the same value? You would need an `update` to change the value later, not an insert. But what is the **real** problem you are trying to solve here? This sounds pretty weird and maybe the underlying problem should be solved in a different way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a view that looks like something like this:

```
create view test_view
as
select a,b,c,d,
       case 
          when a = greatest(a,b,c,d) then 'a' 
          when b = greatest(a,b,c,d) then 'b' 
          when c = greatest(a,b,c,d) then 'c' 
          when d = greatest(a,b,c,d) then 'd' 
       end 
from test;
```

Note that the above will not work correctly if any of the columns contains a `null` value because `greatest()` will return `null` then. If you need to handle that, you need to use e.g.:

```
when a = greatest(coalesce(a,0),coalesce(b,0),coalesce(c,0),coalesce(d,0)) then 'a'
```

When two columns have the same highest value this would display the "first" one. So for `(2,2,4,4)` it would return `c`

Comment: [This answer correctly addresses an earlier version of the question. Note that `a,b,b,c` should be `a,b,c,d`.]